# How to verify email of unauthenticated users using verification code in AWS Amplify?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Cognito as an IDP and AWS Amplify library with Angular application. I also have a .net core application which is using AWS Cognito sdk to perform Admin actions (e.g user cruds). Now when Admin update any user's email, I am chaning email_verified to false so that user must validate his email first. I have a lambda trigger that generates a link and append verification code in the url e.g `http://example.com/username/code`. I'd also created one component in my Angular app to extract the code from url and verify user's email and redirect him/her to login page.

Now the issue is I can't find any such method in AWS amplify that can verify unauthenticated user's email. There are few methods which expects currentUser (authenticated user) but in my scenario the user will not be logged in as Admin had updated the email and also I am using email to login rather username. So only when the email is verified, I can let user to login.

I've also tried using `confirmSignUp()` method in AWS Amplify but it throws "Invalid Code" exception and that's because user's account status is already confirmed, only the email_verified field is false;

How can I verify user's email using the verification code?

Comment: Hey @Ask I am in similar situation, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: This is what happens when the user follows traditional workflow. When the user register and for some reason can not confirm the email, when login if you trap the error you can catch an error that it can be used to confirm the email. In the other hand , if you want to reconfirm the email you can create and trigger lambda functions to validate and confirm email using cognito triggers...